# Spring Boot and Kotlin DSL Configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception

Lately, I have been assigned to a project that disables some of the auto-config and configures the spring boot app mostly manually using KotlinDSL.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
        JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class,
        CassandraAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

I am facing I believe Kotlin lang issue with spring integration.

Let me show you the setup.

1. An abstract sign-in strategy with a @Transactional method in it.
2. A concrete child of the above abstract class. IndividualSignIn with supporting two different implementations. Those are Google and Apple individual sign-ins. The difference maker is the service (Google sign-in service, Apple sign-in service) which is injected into the above concrete class beans. I'll show the setup below.

So, the Kotlin dsl is like the below;

```
bean(name = "googleUserSignIn") {
            IndividualUserSignIn(
                ref("googleUserSignInService"),
                ref("userHibernateDAO"),
                ref("socialAccountHibernateDAO"),
                ref("userService"),
                ...
            )
        }

bean(name = "appleUserSignIn") {
            IndividualUserSignIn(
                ref("appleUserSignInService"),
                ref("userHibernateDAO"),
                ref("socialAccountHibernateDAO"),
                ref("userService"),
                ...
            )
        }
```

And finally, the strategy which proxies the request is like below;

```
bean<UserSignInFactory>()
```

The implementation of these classes are look like below;
first the `AbstractStrategy`

```
abstract class AbstractUserSignIn(
    private val userSignInService: UserSignInService,
    private val userDAO: UserDAO,
    private val socialAccountDAO: SocialAccountDAO,
    private val userService: UserService,
    ....
) {

    @Transactional
    open fun signIn(userSignInRequest: SignInRequest): SignInResult {...}
    
    fun getSignInStrategy(): UserSignInStrategy{ // **(A)**
       return userSignInService.getSignInStrategy()
    }
}
```

Then the classes inherited from this class;

```
open class IndividualUserSignIn constructor(
    userSignInService: UserSignInService,
    userDAO: UserDAO,
    socialAccountDAO: SocialAccountDAO,
    userService: UserService,
    ...
) : AbstractUserSignIn(
    userSignInService,
    userDAO,
    socialAccountDAO,
    userService,
    ...
) {

    @PostConstruct
    private fun init()
    {
        println("strategy :" + getSignInStrategy()) // **(B)**
    }
...
}
```

and the Factory class.

```
@Component
open class UserSignInFactory @Autowired constructor(private val userSignInServices: Set<IndividualUserSignIn>) {

    @PostConstruct
    private fun createStrategies() {
        userSignInServices.forEach { strategy ->
            strategyMap[strategy.getSignInStrategy()] = strategy // **(C)**
        }
    }
    ....
    companion object {
        private val strategyMap: EnumMap<UserSignInStrategy, AbstractUserSignIn> = EnumMap(UserSignInStrategy::class.java)
    }
}
```

Point (A) is where the problem arises. The abstract class uses the injected service to let callers know about its supporting implementation.

Well, here the problem is.

1. At point (B); While the concrete strategies are being instantiated, the @PostConstruct works as expected and prints the supported strategy. Debugging says  **this** is the instance itself of strategy.
2. At point (C); While traversing the Set, I am receiving an NPE because the injected service that is used in point (A) looks null. Here the elements in the **set**, are instances of spring-generated proxies pointing to instances from step #1 above.

Comment: Feels like a problem of **ordering**... you may need to explicitly tell Spring which beans should be instantiated first.  I tried to reproduce using Spring annotations not the DSL approach and it worked for me.  Can you share how you invoke the Kotlin DSL for any Beans/Components created that way?

Comment: @AndrewL thx for the comment but, If you check the item #1 in the summary/problem definition part. The services are being correctly injected for individual signIn strategies. And, in my tests I saw the factory instantiated after the strategies instantiated. I am still somewhere around the Kotlin dsl's behavior. But thx, as per you question how the beans are instantiated;  we are registering ApplicationContextInitializer's for everything including beans, config etc..

Comment: Have you considered defining the concrete strategies as lazy beans? So wrap them to: ```bean(name = "googleUserSignIn") { lazy { IndividualUserSignIn( ........ )  }
}```. Then update UserSignInFactory to accommodate lazy initialization to: ```(private val userSignInServices: Lazy<Set<IndividualUserSignIn>>)``` . So the strategies are instantiated with the correct dependencies injected before they are accessed in the factory. Just an idea.

Comment: @djmonki never thought it but will give it a try, for sure

Comment: @djmonki I tried your comment and it worked. Lazy beans seems to working. At least at that point, but when I check the injected beans, they are not proxies. Which doubts me the @ Transactional gonna work. Still, if you apply your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Apologies for late response, you could try the following to ensure that the injected beans are still proxies, but also initiated as lazy. Reverse the idea I proposed above and annotate the ```IndividualUserSignIn``` class with the following: ```@Lazy``` and ```@Transactional```. See if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider defining the concrete strategies as lazy beans.

This will ensure that the strategies are instantiated with the correct dependencies injected before they are accessed in the factory.

Updated as lazy beans:

```java
bean(name = "googleUserSignIn") {
  lazy {
    IndividualUserSignIn(
      ref("googleUserSignInService"),
      ref("userHibernateDAO"),
      ref("socialAccountHibernateDAO"),
      ref("userService"),
      ...
    )
  }
}

bean(name = "appleUserSignIn") {
  lazy {
    IndividualUserSignIn(
      ref("appleUserSignInService"),
      ref("userHibernateDAO"),
      ref("socialAccountHibernateDAO"),
      ref("userService"),
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

Then update UserSignInFactory class to accommodate lazy initialisation:

```java
@Component
open class UserSignInFactory @Autowired constructor(
  private val userSignInServices: Lazy<Set<IndividualUserSignIn>>) {

  @PostConstruct
  private fun createStrategies() {
    userSignInServices.forEach { strategy ->
      strategyMap[strategy.getSignInStrategy()] = strategy // **(C)**
    }
  }
  ....
  companion object {
    private val strategyMap: 
    EnumMap<UserSignInStrategy, AbstractUserSignIn> = EnumMap(UserSignInStrategy::class.java)
  }
}
```

Comment: Although this seems to be a bit tricky still a way to solve the issue. I accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even the answer already accepted by me, I would like to tell what we come up with and to be honest the correct way to implement. We brought a SignIn **interface** that the abstract class implements and all @Transactional methods defined in the interface. This way, spring is able to proxy the classes (don't know why) and our scenario completed.

Answer (score -3):

it seems that the issue is related to the initialization order of the Spring beans. In particular, the UserSignInFactory bean is being initialized before the beans for IndividualUserSignInService are fully initialized, which is causing the userSignInService field in AbstractUserSignIn to be null when getSignInStrategy() is called.
This can be done using the depends-on attribute of the bean method in Kotlin DSL:

```
@DependsOn("googleUserSignInService")
bean(name = "googleUserSignIn") {
    IndividualUserSignIn(
        ref("googleUserSignInService"),
        ref("userHibernateDAO"),
        ref("socialAccountHibernateDAO"),
        ref("userService")
    )
}

@DependsOn("appleUserSignInService")
bean(name = "appleUserSignIn") {
    IndividualUserSignIn(
        ref("appleUserSignInService"),
        ref("userHibernateDAO"),
        ref("socialAccountHibernateDAO"),
        ref("userService"),
        ...
    )
}
```

Yes, it is true that the dependsOn property does not exist, and I took this example from a code that seemed wrong
I used @DependsOn annotation for correction

Comment: are you sure there is a dependsOn property exists ?

Comment: Looks like ChatGPT. It probably made up the dependsOn property