# Spring Boot Kotlin DSL

Tags: spring-boot, nullpointerexception, kotlin-dsl

lately I have asked a question about dsl config in this question [Spring Boot and Kotlin DSL Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76459395/spring-boot-and-kotlin-dsl-configuration?noredirect=1#comment134895496_76459395)

After some more tests, I figured out that below class's `userSignInService` is not autowired. The proxy does not have the actual instance to service wired to it.

```
bean<AppleUserSignInServiceImpl>(name = "appleUserSignInService")
bean<GoogleUserSignInServiceImpl>(name = "googleUserSignInService")

bean(name="googleSignInStrategy")
        {
                IndividualUserSignIn(
                    ref("googleUserSignInService"),
                    ref("userHibernateDAO"),
                    ref("socialAccountHibernateDAO"),
                    ref("userService"),
                )
        }
----------------------------------------------

open class IndividualUserSignIn constructor(
    userSignInService: UserSignInService,
    userDAO: UserDAO,
    socialAccountDAO: SocialAccountDAO,
    userService: UserService,
) : AbstractUserSignIn(
    userSignInService,
    userDAO,
    socialAccountDAO,
    userService,

----------------------------------------------

abstract class AbstractUserSignIn(
    private val userSignInService: UserSignInService,
    private val userDAO: UserDAO,
    private val socialAccountDAO: SocialAccountDAO,
    private val userService: UserService,
    ....
) {

    @Transactional
    open fun signIn(userSignInRequest: SignInRequest): SignInResult {...}
    
    fun getSignInStrategy(): UserSignInStrategy{ // **(A)**
       return userSignInService.getSignInStrategy()
    }
}
```

If set these to lazy initialization like in [Spring Boot and Kotlin DSL Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76459395/spring-boot-and-kotlin-dsl-configuration?noredirect=1#comment134895496_76459395) then it seems to be working but autowired `IndividualUserSignIn` objects are not **proxy**